# How to suppress knitr/RMarkdown "eval eval withVisible..." output in code chunk with tracemem function?

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown

I have a simple RMarkdown document:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Author"
date: "November 22, 2015"
output: html_document
---

```{r}
x <- 1:10
tracemem(x)
x[2] <- 22
```
````

When I knit this into HTML (using RStudio -> Knit HTML button) it shows a strange output from tracemem ("**eval eval withVisible...**"):

```
x <- 1:10
tracemem(x)
## [1] "<0x32b7c28>"
x[2] <- 22
## tracemem[0x32b7c28 -> 0x33cda68]: eval eval withVisible withCallingHandlers handle evaluate_call <Anonymous> in_dir block_exec call_block process_group.block process_group withCallingHandlers process_file <Anonymous> <Anonymous>
## tracemem[0x33cda68 -> 0x2bcd818]: eval eval withVisible withCallingHandlers handle evaluate_call <Anonymous> in_dir block_exec call_block process_group.block process_group withCallingHandlers process_file <Anonymous> <Anonymous>
```

If I run the same code directly (in R without knitr or via "run current chunk") I get the output as expected:

```
> x <- 1:10
> tracemem(x)
[1] "<0x504eee0>"
> x[2] <- 22
tracemem[0x504eee0 -> 0x5063460]: 
tracemem[0x5063460 -> 0x4feec68]:
```

**Where do these strange "eval eval withVisible..." messages come from and how can I suppress them?**